# Configure Jenkins to take Artifact and Deploy Server Information

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I have configured Frontend and Backend of a project in Jenkins. Frontend using npm and Backend using maven as build tools. For repository management nexus has been configured. Now I want to do the deploy part of this project. For that I need to take artifact list and deploy server list into Jenkins UI. How can I do this? Output should be like below.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

For this I used "Maven Metadata Plugin for Jenkins CI server". I got the answer for "Select Snapshot Version and Select Release Version".